# The __invert__ method

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is the purpose of the `__invert__` method? I was exploring Python internals and came across:

```
>>> dir(__builtins__.int)
['__abs__', '__add__', '__and__', '__bool__', '__ceil__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__divmod__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__float__', '__floor__', '__floordiv__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getnewargs__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__index__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__int__', '__invert__', '__le__', '__lshift__', '__lt__', '__mod__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__neg__', '__new__', '__or__', '__pos__', '__pow__', '__radd__', '__rand__', '__rdivmod__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rfloordiv__', '__rlshift__', '__rmod__', '__rmul__', '__ror__', '__round__', '__rpow__', '__rrshift__', '__rshift__', '__rsub__', '__rtruediv__', '__rxor__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__sub__', '__subclasshook__', '__truediv__', '__trunc__', '__xor__', 'bit_length', 'conjugate', 'denominator', 'from_bytes', 'imag', 'numerator', 'real', 'to_bytes']
```

What surprised me was:

```
__builtins__.int().__invert__()
```

which seemed to break all rules of mathematics because `__builtins__.int()` returns zero and we all know you can't invert *that* integer. Maybe I am missing something... so I dug into the documentation and found `__invert__` is equivalent to bitwise not.

1. Why and how could it be useful to define an *object*'s inversion as its bitwise inverse rather than something more semantically meaningful, a nonzero rationals' inverse is its reciprocal, zero doesn't have one, complexes take a different tack, a methods inverse reverses the state or is not defined etc.

   Could someone give an example of a situation where taking the bitwise-not of an *instance* of class/object is a useful construction at the high level (i.e. not at the compiler/interpreter optimization level).
2. Python documentation states type of an object returns an object itself, so why couldn't we get away with defining inversion of zero as None or NaN object?

Comment: `int()` returns zero, sure, but zero is still an integer with all the methods any integer has.  [`__invert__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__invert__) is the "magic method" for `~`.

Comment: I somewhat disagree, zero is neither odd nor even, not positive nor negative, and does not have an inverse. Sure none of those methods are implemented, but calling zero just another integer is … a cop out. And integers don't _need_ `real`, `imag`, `denominator` or `conj` methods.

Comment: I didn't say it was any of those things, I just said it was an integer, *the Python type*. You seem to be confusing OOP and mathematics. It's useful for all numbers to share methods and attributes so they meet the requirements of the Liskov substitution principle/"duck typing" and you don't fill your code with type checks. Maybe "invert" isn't the best name for bitwise not in some contexts, but that's not really a question for SO.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yeah maybe … there is always discord between notation, mathematics and implementation.  If the question is not going to be closed I would appreciate  answers to the other questions.

Comment: Then please [edit] to ask one practical, answerable question per the [help/on-topic].

Comment: But they are all related Jon! Its one direct line of inquiry…. fine. First one here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54785425/why-does-the-builtin-int-class-have-real-image-conj-etc-as-attributes

Answer (score 16):

`__invert__` is the implementation of the "binary not" operator `~` -- it has absolutely nothing to do with any formal definition of the word "invert" in mathematics

for the integer 0, using 2s complement, the binary negation of `0b000...000` is `0b111...111` -- or `-1` in decimal

```
>>> ~int()
-1
>>> int().__invert__()
-1
>>> ~0
-1
```

Comment: @Gopal no: (for example a 1 byte integer) 0b0000_0000 inverted is 0b1111_1111 or -1