# Why does the built-in int_class have 'real', 'image', 'conj' etc as attributes?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was exploring Python internals and came across:

```
>>> dir(__builtins__.int)
['__abs__', '__add__', '__and__', '__bool__', '__ceil__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__divmod__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__float__', '__floor__', '__floordiv__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getnewargs__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__index__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__int__', '__invert__', '__le__', '__lshift__', '__lt__', '__mod__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__neg__', '__new__', '__or__', '__pos__', '__pow__', '__radd__', '__rand__', '__rdivmod__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rfloordiv__', '__rlshift__', '__rmod__', '__rmul__', '__ror__', '__round__', '__rpow__', '__rrshift__', '__rshift__', '__rsub__', '__rtruediv__', '__rxor__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__sub__', '__subclasshook__', '__truediv__', '__trunc__', '__xor__', 'bit_length', 'conjugate', 'denominator', 'from_bytes', 'imag', 'numerator', 'real', 'to_bytes']
```

which is fine but a bit confusing because: why should have an integer class have `real`, `imag`, `denominator` and `conjugate` as attributes? I note that they don't have the `__<item>__` format, but it just seems odd.

Comment: Because they're [`numbers`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/numbers.html#module-numbers)? Also note you can just do `dir(int)`.

Comment: And it isn't wasteful? I mean i know all real numbers have no conjugates and no imaginary parts and denominators only make sense if you are talking about rationals which are superset of the integers.

Comment: What do you mean *"wasteful"*? Of what? Again you seem to be treating these as mathematical not OOP types.

Comment: Well maybe in my math head, they seem extraneous; you are defining properties for integers that dont exist. Can you clarify why they dont have the `__<item>__` format?

Comment: Why *would* they have the `__dunder__` format? They're not "magic methods", from e.g. the [data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html), they're actual attributes of the instances.

Comment: Real numbers have a conjugate (themselves), an imaginary part (0), and so on. Why would taking the conjugate of a real number fail, though it is perfectly defined, just because you didn't explicitely represent it as a complex?

Comment: Because as soon as I import numpy I have a choice between, ints, floats, complexes etc. In the end, we seem to eventually make the distinction. 

And as per orders, i open a new question to get a downvote: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54784932/the-invert-method. 
 Nice.

Comment: Every ints can be seen as a complex number with a 0 imaginary part, likewise also a fraction with a denominator of 1.

Comment: @ITA which "downvote" ? Voting to close a question is not a downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ints have imag and real parts to support mixed numeric arithmetic. It is completely fine (mathematically and in Python) to add an real integer to a complex number. Python supports this by adding the imag and real attributes to the int class. In Python mixed numeric type arithmetic, the "narrower" type is "widened" to the less-narrow type. This means int's get widened to floats and complex numbers when they are used together.

See [Numeric types - int, float, complex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex)